# How does searching for a vertex happen in graph databases using gremlin (Apache TinkerPop)?

Tags: java, graph-databases, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am working on modeling my data such as ->

```
data: [
 {
  id:"123",
  type:"a",
  attributes: [...]
 },
 {entity 2 ...},
 {entity 3 ...},
 ...
]
```

Is there a gremlin query I can use to fetch/get the vertex by type and id instead of just id?
If not, would I have to traverse and search, if so what would the performance look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type of entity in Gremlin is called `Label`.

To get a vertex by id and verify it has specific label you can run the query:

```
g.V('123').hasLabel('a').next()
```

If type is just a regular property (attribute) you can run:

```
g.V('123').has('type', 'a').next()
```

Performance depends on implementation, but getting vertex by id should be O(1) in any case.

Comment: I accepted it, I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet. 
Another question:
Can I have 2 separate nodes with the same id but a different label?
for e.g.:
 Vertex 1
  label="Customer"
  id="123"

 Vertex 2
  label="Account"
  id="123"

Comment: No, you cannot have the same ID for different vertices.